# Trigger a pipeline X times a day

Tags: jfrog-pipelines

I have a use-case where i want to run a specific pipeline X times a day, is there a recommendation on efficient way to achieve this?

For example, i have a pipeline which will need to run *10 times* a day with different parameters and store it's result to understand the stability of the pipeline.

I have looked at [crontrigger](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/CronTrigger), is this the best approach?

Answer (score 1):

I would say `Cron` is the best tool.

You can find tools to generate Cron expressions, such as this one: https://crontab.cronhub.io/

as well as platforms that help you monitor your Cron job, such as this one: https://cronhub.io/